# How to refresh DetailViewController when MasterViewController is updated

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an application where the users can update and add tasks. But when the users update the task I need to update the details in the DetailViewController[image]

When the users updates the task and saves the data in MasterViewController saves but the data in DetailViewController stays the same
[image]

How can I fix it so that the details get updated as well

The tasks are added and edited using the **AddProjectController**

I tried the following methods but none if them worked, all caused the the application to crash

```
 let vc = DetailViewController()
 let row = vc.view.layoutIfNeeded();

//Second method

let vc = MasterViewController() 
vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: vc.self)
```

The data is set in the DetailViewController using

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self

        lblName.text = detail.name ?? ""
        lblCode.text = detail.code ?? ""     
    }
```

MasterViewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
   if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
       let object = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
       let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.details = object;
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                detailViewController = controller
            }
    }
}
```

EditViewController

```
func editEvents(_ sender: Any){
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Proj")

        do {
            let test = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            var objectUpdate = test[0] as! Assesment;


            objectUpdate.name = txtname.text ?? ""
            objectUpdate.code = txtCode.text ?? "";

            do {
                try context.save()

            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I want to update the details when the editEvent function is finished executing

Is there anyway I can get this to work?

Comment: you need to use closures or delegate for messaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are using coreData .. You can implement FRC in details .. so you get refreshed data every time in callback ...

In your `MasterViewController` define a variable

Here is another workaround

```
private var controller : DetailViewController? = nil
```

Then in your Segue method use this controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
   if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
       let object = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
       self.controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController // here you set your instence variable controller
                controller.details = object;
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                detailViewController = controller
            }
    }
}


func editEvents(_ sender: Any){
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Proj")

        do {
            let test = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            var objectUpdate = test[0] as! Assesment;


            objectUpdate.name = txtname.text ?? ""
            objectUpdate.code = txtCode.text ?? "";



            do {
                try context.save()
                if let detailsCotrollerExists = controller {
                 detailsCotrollerExists.updateDataWithObject(objectUpdate) // function you will write in detail class which takes object and refresh data there .. Either outlets or Table/Collection View reload
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Then you write a function in `DetailViewController` `func updateDataWithObject(_ obj: Assesment)`  function you will write in detail class which takes object and refresh data there .. Either outlets or Table/Collection View reload
Write function in `DetailViewController`

```
func updateDataWithObject(_ obj: Assesment) {
  // Refresh data
}
```